# Probability of guessing a coupon code with the following pattern?

Tags: random, probability, calculation

I'm generating coupons with the following charset:

1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ (36 Characters)

Using this pattern: (replace hash tag with a character)

```
####-####-####-#### (16 chars)
```

36^16 = 7,958,661,109,946,400,884,391,936

How do you figure out the probability of guessing a code if I generated 1000 codes randomly?

Comment: seems like a question for https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Which language? Where is the source code of the try?

Answer (score 2):

Basically since you're generating each new code randomly (so there could be dups), each generation has a:

```
1/36^16 probability of being correct
```

...so the chance that none of the codes are correct are:

```
[(36^16-1)/36^16)]^1000
```

...and so the probability of guessing the code is 1 minus this:

```
1 - [(36^16-1)/36^16)]^1000
```